# python subprocess Popen is not delivering stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, interactive

I know that similar questions have been asked many times, but I didn't manage to apply those solutions to my case.

I have this interactive program:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                   

echo "banana"                                                                                                                                                               
while true                                                                                                                                                                  
do                                                                                                                                                                          
    read line                                                                                                                                                               
    echo $line                                                                                                                                                              
done
```

and I am trying to communicate with it via python, but this happens:

```
> python3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 24 2013, 16:43:21) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT
>>> p = Popen("x.sh", stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)
>>> print(p.stdout.readline())
b'banana\n'
>>> p.stdin.write(bytes('xyzgewgwer','UTF-8'))
10
>>> print(p.stdout.readline())
```

sometimes it hangs there, but sometimes it prints

```
b''
```

any idea?

Comment: The program is not going to be able to echo the line *until you've given it a full line* - try putting `\n` at the end of the string you're writing to the program.

Comment: Nope, readline() is still stuck

Comment: @Patrik, did you receive the answer you were looking for ?

Comment: No, I didn't, but I didn't try to flush the output buffer inside my interactive program

Answer (score 1):

You should use `communicate` and `wait`

**Example:**

```
import subprocess
cmd="x.sh"
prc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
prc.stdin.write("yo\n")
stdout, stderr = prc.communicate()
prc.wait()
print (stdout)
```

Comment: communicate is a no-go. Documentation says "Wait for process to terminate" but I need an interactive solution. Sent something to stdin, read stout, send someting else to stdin based on what I received